# How do I convert a 24-bit/96 kHz FLAC to anything else?

Tags: audio, file-conversion, flac

I have some FLAC files I want to convert to AAC, but I can't because my go-to program, [Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/), throws an exception (`The call to ExtAudioFileSetProperty failed.`) when it tries to convert 24-bit/96 kHz FLAC (16-bit is no problem) to any other format.

So is there another good program for converting from FLAC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I use a tool called **X Lossless Decoder**, or [**XLD**](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) for short. I use it for converting FLAC to Apple Lossless regularly, and it’s never hiccupped.

From the [project’s page](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html):

> XLD can decode following formats:
>
> - (Ogg) FLAC (.flac/.oga)
> - […]

and:

> XLD supports various output formats. It can convert audio files into […] MPEG-4 AAC (QuickTime/CoreAudio), MP3 (LAME), Apple Lossless, FLAC […].

XLD is free, and is still being actively maintained. Highly recommended.

Comment: Just want to confirm that XLD can convert 24-bit/96 kHz FLAC without a hitch.